# Passing parameters in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, addeventlistener, dom-events

I am working on a Firefox extension, and I am trying to pass a parameter to addEventListener. I am "listening" for changes in the page title, my code looks something like this:

```
function Test()
{
    this.checkTitle = function( event )
    {
        var func = function() { this.onTitleChange ( event ); };
        var target = content.document.getElementsByTagName('TITLE')[0];
        target.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', func, false);
    }

    this.onTitleChange = function( e )
    {
        // do stuff with e
        alert('test');
    }

    this.handleEvent = function (event)
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case "DOMContentLoaded":
            {
                this.checkTitle( event );
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", this, false);
}
```

I never get the 'test' alert, if I use func = function() { alert(event); }; it does show an alert with '[object Event]'. Also tried without using this. on func but still wont work.

**How can I make this work to be able to access checkTitle parameter "event" into onTitleChange?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the browser calls the event handler, `this` will refer to the element, not your instance.

You need to save a copy of the desired `this` in a separate variable:

```
var self = this;

var func = function(e) { self.onTitleChange (e); };
var target = content.document.getElementsByTagName('TITLE')[0];
target.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', func, false);
```

Comment: This helped a lot, but only after I've changed the 2nd line to:    var func = function(event) { self.onTitleChange ( event ); };